# How to priortized the test cases in maven run?

Tags: maven, selenium, junit4

I have 3 test cases i.e. 1 2 3. How will i give priority as 2 1 3 while executing maven command.

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I have three test cases Create, Delete and share, all are working on same element say for example. If you run delete before create there will not be anything to delete. So i need to order them in this fashion :
Create
, Share
and last Delete.

Comment: It's stupid, I know, but if you change order of you tests cases in your test class, it will work as you want :)

Comment: :) its not answer. But if it is the answer then stackoverflow will kick me out :)

Comment: I strongly recommend against using an order for this. Instead use different items in each of the tests and either create or ensure one does not exist in the arrange part of the test. Why? As if one of the tests fails personally I would run JUST that test to work out what is going on. Except that test will not execute but for a different reason. Keep your tests isolated. It just makes life easier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to do it because you need some prerequisition prior the test can be run. You can do it by `@Before` Annotation prior the actual testcase, or you can call other tests from the test method.

Say, `testClient()` test will test and verify that new client can be added to the system. Then you can do this:

```
@Test 
public void testWithdrawal(){
 testClient(); // i need client existing before the test can be run
 // ... do something else
}
```

In that case you have assured that prerequisites are fullfilled and dont have to worry much about the testcases order

**EDIT**

I think I understand your needs, because I am in quite similar situation. How I solved it:

For `create` I have special class, which can create me a data and return needed data. So, i have something like:

```
@Test
public void testShare(){
CreateTests create = new CreateTests; //This will just initialize the object
create.testCreate(); // this method can contain steps needed to create
String justCreatedEntity = create.getEntity(); // just example how you can use the just created entity in further tests

}
```

And my class to solve the create is something like this

```
public class CreateTests{
  private static String entity; //static because i dont want it to be flushed when test ends

 public void testCreate() throws Exception{

    WebDriverBackedSelenium selenium = new WebDriverBackedSelenium(driver, "baseURL");
    selenium.... // All the selenium stuff
     setEntity(selenium.getText("id=mainForm.createdentity"));
 }

 public void setEntity(String ent){
  this.entity = ent;
 }

 public String getEntity(){
  return entity;
 }
```

Its just an outline - but basically, I have these "crucial" entities as standalone objects, called by the test class. Inside test, i verify everything throgh getters. Like:

```
Assert.assertNotNull(create.getAuctionID(),"New Entity is NULL!" );
```

Comment: No Pavel, JUnit setUp() and teardown() are the prerequisites. My problem is a race condition. I will try to make it more clear, there are three individual unit tests Create Delete and  Share working on same data set i.e. what do i create using Create will be  shared and deleted using Share and Delete. So if i call Create->Delete->Share then there will nothing to share. So i need to set the order such as Create->Share->Delete. I think its clear now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks Pavel, my question was actually at the command level. Like when you type **mvn -Dtest=create, share, delete test**. It should take this order.

Comment: I dont know how to achieve exactly that approach, but if you refactor your code to match the example, you will have always assured, that the test runs in order Create - Share - Delete without any external switchers

Comment: I will surely use this approach. I will tell you how it goes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can run mvn test with options to specify a single test, or multiple tests.  The order they are run in is the order specified on the command line.

Reference is here: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/single-test.html

Note that Java suggests that the good unit testing practice of tests not requiring to be run in order and test to not rely on each other:
http://java.sun.com/developer/Books/javaprogramming/ant/ant_chap04.pdf

Comment: I have used -Dtest command but it did not work. May be i have given the wrong commands. Thanks.